Workbook Performance
I created a macro that copies several sheets from my current work book and creates a sperate workbook with the copied sheets. (The copied sheets contain many formulas and when pasting into the new workbook I paste the values). The problem I'm experiencing is that I get a small message at the top of the new workbook stating "SLOW WORKBOOK? 56% of your workbook has unused formatting and metadata that can be optimized to improve performance." Using the "Check Performance" function under the review tab it displays the ranges and the data in the cells that need to be optimized are all miscellaneous. How would I go about fixing this using VBA?
In my code I reformat the cells in the new workbook, before I was reformatting the entire column but I changed that to go to the last row of data. That fixed some of the performance issues but still left the "remove miscellaneous" option.

Can you show us the relevant parts of your code? If you are just copying the values, consider assigning them to a range (ex.: Range("A1").Value = "text")

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@cybernetic.nomad I just discovered it happens when I delete a row Sheets(i).Rows(1).Delete . Before that line of code runs there are no optimizations to be made
